# Easiest way to map route in PHP

Tags: php, dictionary, routes

I was browsing Symfony's website. I didn't really feel like I need all the functionality the framework offers, but I did like the routing part. It allows you to specify URL pattern like this

```
/some/path/{info}
```

Now for URL like `www.somewebsite.com/app.php/some/path/ANYTHING` it would allow you to send client a response specific for this URL. You could also use string ANYTHING and use it similar as GET parameter.
There is also option to hide app.php part of the URL which leaves us URL like `www.somewebsite.com/some/path/ANYTHING`.
My question is what's best approach to do this without a complex framework?

Comment: Are you talking about [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting)?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that's the name for that

Comment: I have reverted back to the original wording. Think of users who are not familiar with the concept like you and would search the same wording as him. Keep the current wording and explain what URL rewriting is.

Comment: Oli is right what he needs is to learn and understand what url rewriting is, you can do it without using any php framework. In fact most of frameworks uses apache mod_rewrite to make friendly and nice url's

Comment: The original title seems fine to me. _URL rewriting_ is the broad name for a custom URL structure, and _routing_ is the specific process of mapping sets of URIs onto sets of controllers. All IMO, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend this article http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/ to understand url rewrite using apache mod_rewrite you do not need any framework just php. Also this is what in the depth any framework implements

Answer (score 7):

I have made my own mini-framework with the same routing syntax. Here's what I do:

1. Use MOD_REWRITE to store the parameters (like `/some/path/{info}`) in a `$_GET` variable I call `params`:

   `RewriteRule ^(.+)(\?.+)?$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]`
2. Parse the parameters and store them globally using this function:

```
public static function parseAndGetParams() {

        // get the original query string

        $params = !empty($_GET['params']) ? $_GET['params'] : false;

        // if there are no params, set to false and return
        if(empty($params)) {
            return false;
        }

        // append '/' if none found
        if(strrpos($params, '/') === false) $params .= '/';

        $params = explode('/', $params);
        // take out the empty element at the end
        if(empty($params[count($params) - 1])) array_pop($params);

        return $params;
    }
```

3. Route to the proper page dynamically:

   ```
   // get the base page string, must be done after params are parsed
   public static function getCurPage() {
       global $params;

       // default is home
       if(empty($params))
       return self::PAGE_HOME;
       // see if it is an ajax request
       else if($params[0] == self::PAGE_AJAX)
       return self::PAGE_AJAX;
       // see if it is a multi param page, and if not, return error
       else {
           // store this, as we are going to use it in the loop condition
           $numParams = count($params);

           // initialize to full params array
           $testParams = $params;
           // $i = number of params to include in the current page name being checked, {1, .., n}
           for($i = $numParams; $i > 0; $i--) {
               // get test page name
               $page = strtolower(implode('/', $testParams));

               // if the page exists, return it
               if(self::pageExists($page))
                   return $page;

               // pop the last param off
               array_pop($testParams);
           }

           // page DNE go to error page
           return self::PAGE_ERROR;
       }
   }
   ```

The **value** here is that it looks for the *most specific* page to the *least specific* page. Also, workout outside of a framework gives you *complete control* so if there's a bug somewhere, you know you can fix it - you don't have to look up some weird workaround in your framework.

So now that `$params` is global, any page that uses a parameter simply calls `$params[X]` to work with it. Friendly URLs without a framework.

The way I add pages then is I put them into an array that is looked at in the `pageExists($page)` call.

For AJAX calls, I put in a special **IF**:

```
// if ajax, include it and finish
if($page == PageHelper::PAGE_AJAX) {
    PageHelper::includeAjaxPage();
    $db->disconnect();
    exit;
}
```

And voila - your own micro routing framework.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a routing is a complex thing in a framework.

Perhaps you take a look at [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/documentation). Its a micro-framework based on the Symfony2 Components. Its not so big as Symfony2 but have some of the features.