# How to have clean URL's in PHP

Tags: php, url, clean-urls

Is there any way I can have good looking URL in PHP? any default php URL would look like this: http://example.com/something/?post=something But Is It possible to have It like this: http://example.com/something/user Is It possible to remove ?post= without using .htaccess

Here is some example code that I have been working on, Which on click of a post It would access my database and load the content:

```
<?php 

if(!isset($_GET['post'])) {
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postID='something'");
} else {
    $id = $_GET['post'];
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postID='$id'");
}

$p = mysql_fetch_object($q);

?>
```

**Thank you for your Time!**

Comment: Learn URL Rewritin with .htaccess

Comment: Eiter use .htaccess rules or if you are working with Wordpress you could dig into http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API, which is a wrapper for .htaccess

Comment: We do not use WordPress, We have our own CMS.

Comment: You should investigate how WordPress works it'll be useful for you.

Comment: I will Thanks for the Tip!

Answer (score 1):

To get clean URLs you'll have to use mod_rewrite module, but you can minimize it's use, if you leave url parsing to your own script and have only one **entry point**. Look how it's made in WordPress:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So if there's no real file or directory that is requested in URL, each and every request is redirected to `index.php` and then parsed by some internal route mapping script.

There's an example of such script in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078816/easiest-way-to-map-route-in-php).

Comment: Yeah; have a Google for "PHP URL routing"; you'll find a bunch of decent explanations/tutorials on how a single entry point with the dispatching done in code works.

Comment: Is that .htaccess or PHP?

Comment: How can .htaccess help me? Because my URL's are dynamic all postID are Dynamic.

Comment: @mrezajafari gave you a link for FrontController pattern, read it - everything is explained there. Briefly, you redirect every request to `index.php`, which then parses `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and calls needed function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for having clean URL use one of php frameworks which default have this ability.
if you want to use pure php you should use a Router in your project which means you should write your own php framework.
have you ever worked with any php framework??
I suggest using laravel or cakephp for entry point of learning php frameworks.

Comment: I suggest start using laravel. it's easy to use and also easy to learn . laravel has so many vide tutorials and simple documantaion to learn. if you have'nt used any framework before , it's not wise to start writing your own framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a Router and Dispatcher in your project.The Router extracts url and dispatcher calls that function related to url.in the other word,you should impelement **frontcontroller** design pattern in your project.I suggest check this tutorial
http://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/