# How to route url in core php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes

I am trying to rewrite url using htaccess but i have many modules folder and more are coming so i want to rewrite using php or in other word routing.
I am using core php but i an trying to make it like a framework as we can't write view folder or controller folder we just directly call a file name.

My current htaccess code is below but i am not satisfy with htaccess i want to do this with php

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/*.php
 RewriteRule ^(.*)google_api_create_update.php$ dashboard_setting/v1/google_api_setting/v1.01/*.php$1 [L]
```

Comment: You need to do *some* kind of reroute at the server level to retrieve the correct resource if the URL path doesn't match the filesystem path. Generally you'd just punt everything doesn't exist to */index.php* which uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to work out what to do.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078816/easiest-way-to-map-route-in-php